# Netop Host slow to load on desktops – Can it launch faster?

Tags: remote-access

So we use the software *Netop* to remote desktop into servers. Some users also run *Netop host* on their pc's so they can Netop in from home. The problem is if the user is running *Netop host* they need to stop it in order to run *Netop Guest* so they remote in to other servers.

The problem is, it takes about 5 minutes for the *host* program to launch, but I have no idea why. Is there a way to make the *host* launch faster?

Answer (score 0):

If the 
[COEXISTENCE]
COEXIST=2
into the C:\Windows\netop.ini and you have changed the ports (you can't have the same ports running on both Guest and Host at the same time), that should work.

Comment: I checked and was set to COEXIST=2, but I am not sure how to change the ports, how do you?